# jQuery: Adding CSS to parent

Tags: javascript, jquery

I work with popup windows and want to make it possible to close them.

This is my code:

```js
$(".close").click(function() {
  $(".window").css("display", "none");
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Arial;
}

.window {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: tomato;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.close {
  float: right;
}

.close:hover {
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="window">Hi.
  <div class="close">X</div>
</div>
<div class="window">I love you.
  <div class="close">X</div>
</div>
<div class="window">Thanks.
  <div class="close">X</div>
</div>
```

If you click one `X`, all windows disappear. But only the clicked window should disappear.

How is it possible to do that? :)

Thank you very much for your help! <3

Comment: Note that `hide()` and `show()` are simpler to use than `css('display...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following

```
$(".close").click(function() {
  $(this).parents('.window').css("display", "none");
});
```

Demo - https://codepen.io/vyspiansky/pen/zYqNxXd